# Img tags clashing

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, attributes

I am building a website and on the landing page I have a couple of images with a javascript interaction. These are being brought by javascript instead of html and they are on an .img on css.

````
``` img{position: absolute; top: 500px; left: 400px; transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0.2); animation: fadein 0.5s;} ```
````

On the second page of the website I have more images but I have put them together as grid with Responsive equal height images using CSS.

```
.img {width: 100%; height: auto; vertical-align: middle;}
```

My problem is that the second page is using the .img attributes from the first page and not the second one and I am not sure how to differentiate them?

Here's a picture of how the left page should be looking vs how it's looking.

[picture of what should be looking vs how it's looking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RnLiv.jpg)

I am really running on a tight deadline but I can't seem to fix this, does anybody know what could I do? :(

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

The img selector is too vague, it will target any img on the page. You should make it more specific.
You have to create a different CSS class for each case.

Comment: Yes I have tried to do that by adding a div class around the images for the second page. However he still targets the original .img from the first page...

Comment: Even if you wrap it inside a div it would still be targeted by the selector. It's way too vague.

Comment: So what do you think it's my best solution for this?

Comment: replace the `img` selector with some more specific selector which you'll have to also put in the images you want to target.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are using `img { }` in CSS. This is fine for when you want all the images to be styled the same way, however you want separate styling for separate images. To overcome this we use selectors.

[Use a class](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_selectors.asp). A class selector will only style tags that have `class=""` in them, in this case `<img>` tags

```
img.page1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 500px;
    left: 400px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0.2);
    animation: fadein 0.5s;
}

img.page2 {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Now if you add `class="page1"` and `class="page2"` respectively to your images and/or containers, the images will use the CSS formating for their own class.

Something like this `<img class="page1" src="my_image.jpg">`

Or `<div class="page1"> (<img> tags here...) </div>` will also work and will save you putting the class for each `<img>` tag

Comment: Thank you so much! However, I have tried that but it keeps targeting the first .img selector unfortunately

Comment: @rita The HTML code will use the .img styling if it cannot find the class that you referred to. Make sure you've defined the classes correctly and added class="classname" to the tags.

Comment: @rita To debug it, maybe you could remove the .img selector?

Comment: So I have tried to do as you said:  I added the <class="page2"> around two div class tags which have inside of them <div class="div1"><img src="5.jpg"> </div> images like this. I think I probably am not defining the classes correctly? But I am not sure how to fix it?

Comment: Does the class look like this in CSS: img.div1 { } ? - The only other thing it could be is if the .css file isn't linker, OR the div has the class, but your CSS styling isn't working correctly.

I usually try adding a background colour to my CSS to see if its working, try adding 'background-color:red;' to it and make sure that it is working.

Comment: @rita What do your classes look like, and what are the class="" inside your tags???

Comment: ok let's see if I can explain this properly: So on my second page I wanted to do a weird grid with responsive equal height images using CSS. For this I created two different div classes one called <div class="parent"> , the other <div class="parents">. and then within this there's 7 div classes in each with img srcs like this: <div class="div1"><img src="5.jpg"> </div>. I had to do it this way so that I could put the ratios of each image on a flex so that all images could have the same height. (I hope this is making sense sorry for the mess)

Comment: on the css the class looks like .img or .img2 I always tried it that way but I am going to try using .imgdiv1!